# (JavaFX) How can I change a text's color in a textfield depending on the validity of the input?

Tags: javafx, input, textfield

I need to know how to change the text color of a textfield. If the input is invalid, the text should change to red. If it's valid, it should change to back to black. The color needs to change when I click off the textfield.

I have tried using an EventHandler, which does sort of work, but there's a delay when I click off the textfield. My professor says to use bindings, but I'm not sure what to bind what to.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import org.junit.Test;


public class DataEntryGUI extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(30, 30, 30, 30));
        root.setHgap(5.5);
        root.setVgap(5.5);

        // TextFields
        NameTextField firstName = new NameTextField();
        firstName.setPromptText("Name");
        firstName.setOnMouseExited(e -> NameTextField.nameIsValid(firstName));

        NameTextField secondName = new NameTextField();
        secondName.setPromptText("Name");
        secondName.setOnMouseExited(e -> NameTextField.nameIsValid(secondName));

        NameTextField thirdName = new NameTextField();
        thirdName.setPromptText("Name");
        thirdName.setOnMouseExited(e -> NameTextField.nameIsValid(thirdName));

        PhoneTextField firstNumber = new PhoneTextField();
        firstNumber.setPromptText("(###) ###-####");
        firstNumber.setOnMouseExited(e -> PhoneTextField.phoneIsValid(firstNumber));

        PhoneTextField secondNumber = new PhoneTextField();
        secondNumber.setPromptText("(###) ###-####");
        secondNumber.setOnMouseExited(e -> PhoneTextField.phoneIsValid(secondNumber));

        PhoneTextField thirdNumber = new PhoneTextField();
        thirdNumber.setPromptText("(###) ###-####");
        thirdNumber.setOnMouseExited(e -> PhoneTextField.phoneIsValid(thirdNumber));

        // "Create Profiles" button
        StackPane btnPane = new StackPane();
        Button btn = new Button("Create Profiles");
        btnPane.getChildren().add(btn);
        StackPane.setAlignment(btn, Pos.CENTER);

        //Enable/Disable button depending on if any TextField is empty
        btn.disableProperty().bind(firstName.textProperty().isEmpty()
            .or(secondName.textProperty().isEmpty()).or(thirdName.textProperty().isEmpty())
            .or(firstNumber.textProperty().isEmpty()).or(secondNumber.textProperty().isEmpty())
            .or(thirdNumber.textProperty().isEmpty()));

        // Layout of window
        root.add(firstName, 0, 0);
        root.add(secondName, 0, 1);
        root.add(thirdName, 0, 2);
        root.add(firstNumber, 1, 0);
        root.add(secondNumber, 1, 1);
        root.add(thirdNumber, 1, 2);
        root.add(btnPane, 0, 3, 2, 3);

        // Creating scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Data Entry GUI");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}



import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class NameTextField extends TextField{
    public NameTextField(){
        super();
    }
    public NameTextField(String text){
        super(text);
    }
    public static void nameIsValid(NameTextField input) {
        String text = input.getText();
        if (text.split(" ").length != 2)
            input.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
        else
            input.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: black;");
    }
}



import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javax.xml.soap.Text;


public class PhoneTextField extends TextField {
    public PhoneTextField(){
        super();
    }
    public PhoneTextField(String text){
        super(text);
    }
    public static void phoneIsValid(PhoneTextField input){
        String text = input.getText();
        if (text.split(" ").length != 2)
            input.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
        else
            return;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be checking the validity every time the mouse cursor leaves the `TextField`? Wouldn't it be better to wait for it to lose focus instead?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it on the `textProperty` of the field:

```
textField.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> o, String oldValue, String newValue) ->
{                             
    if (!isStringValidPhoneNumber(newValue))
    {
        textField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red ; -fx-border-width: 1px ;");
    } else
    {                
        textField.setStyle(null);               
    }

}

public static boolean isStringValidPhoneNumber (String field)
{
    // do the validating here
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So to start off there is a few things you should re-think such as individually setting the `setPromptText(...);` to the same thing if you are constantly re-typing the same thing there is a good chance it can be done more efficiently so I created an initialize method that does the things you are re-typing  this means when the class is initialized it will run is whatever's in that method I also removed static from the `nameIsValid()` method as it was not needed as well as the textfield input parameter. Then I fire the name is valid method on the textfield loosing focus as it is a better design. Take a look at the end result below

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(30, 30, 30, 30));
        root.setHgap(5.5);
        root.setVgap(5.5);

        // TextFields
        NameTextField firstName = new NameTextField();
//        firstName.setPromptText("Name");
//        firstName.setOnMouseExited(e -> NameTextField.nameIsValid(firstName));

        NameTextField secondName = new NameTextField();
//        secondName.setPromptText("Name");
//        secondName.setOnMouseExited(e -> NameTextField.nameIsValid(secondName));

        NameTextField thirdName = new NameTextField();
//        thirdName.setPromptText("Name");
//        thirdName.setOnMouseExited(e -> NameTextField.nameIsValid(thirdName));

        PhoneTextField firstNumber = new PhoneTextField();
//        firstNumber.setPromptText("(###) ###-####");
//        firstNumber.setOnMouseExited(e -> PhoneTextField.phoneIsValid(firstNumber));

        PhoneTextField secondNumber = new PhoneTextField();
//        secondNumber.setPromptText("(###) ###-####");
//        secondNumber.setOnMouseExited(e -> PhoneTextField.phoneIsValid(secondNumber));

        PhoneTextField thirdNumber = new PhoneTextField();
//        thirdNumber.setPromptText("(###) ###-####");
//        thirdNumber.setOnMouseExited(e -> PhoneTextField.phoneIsValid(thirdNumber));

        // "Create Profiles" button
        StackPane btnPane = new StackPane();
        Button btn = new Button("Create Profiles");
        btnPane.getChildren().add(btn);
        StackPane.setAlignment(btn, Pos.CENTER);

        //Enable/Disable button depending on if any TextField is empty
        btn.disableProperty().bind(firstName.textProperty().isEmpty()
                .or(secondName.textProperty().isEmpty()).or(thirdName.textProperty().isEmpty())
                .or(firstNumber.textProperty().isEmpty()).or(secondNumber.textProperty().isEmpty())
                .or(thirdNumber.textProperty().isEmpty()));

        // Layout of window
        root.add(firstName, 0, 0);
        root.add(secondName, 0, 1);
        root.add(thirdName, 0, 2);
        root.add(firstNumber, 1, 0);
        root.add(secondNumber, 1, 1);
        root.add(thirdNumber, 1, 2);
        root.add(btnPane, 0, 3, 2, 3);

        // Creating scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Data Entry GUI");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    public class NameTextField extends TextField {
        public NameTextField(){
            super();
            initialize();
        }
        public NameTextField(String text){
            super(text);
            initialize();
        }
//        public static void nameIsValid(NameTextField input) {
        private void nameIsValid() {
            String text = this.getText();
            if (text.split(" ").length != 2)
                this.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red; -fx-text-inner-color: red;");
            else
                this.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: black;");
        }
        private void initialize() {
            this.setPromptText("Name");
            this.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldPropertyValue, newPropertyValue) -> {
                if (oldPropertyValue)
                    nameIsValid();
            });
        }
    }

    public class PhoneTextField extends TextField{
        public PhoneTextField(){
            super();
            initialize();
        }
        public PhoneTextField(String text){
            super(text);
            initialize();
        }
//        public static void phoneIsValid(PhoneTextField input){
        private void phoneIsValid(){
            String text = this.getText();
            if (text.split(" ").length != 2)
                this.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red; -fx-text-inner-color: red;");
            else
                this.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: black;");

        }
        private void initialize() {
            this.setPromptText("(###) ###-####");
            this.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldPropertyValue, newPropertyValue) -> {
                if (oldPropertyValue)
                    phoneIsValid();
            });
        }
    }
}
```